# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [fifth moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Masked Man] [image: Snow]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5640602439909376/0).

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Never expected that. I’m rather chuffed... well done to the masked one also! And the rest of the candidates,there was some real competition there!

Comment: Told you that you were jinxing it! Congrats you two

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations to MaskedMan and Snow. I have had the pleasure of interacting with the former, but I have faith in your talents. Remember the words of Uncle Ben, "With great power comes great responsibility". Wishing you a satisfying time here. :)

Comment: Interesting that the "surplus votes" stage has been reached. It was a rather tight election.

Answer (score 18):

Congratulations to @Snow and @MaskedMan!!

Comment: Thank you for standing, DarkCygnus and all the other candidates.

Comment: No problem @MonicaCellio :) like Snow said, we had some excellent candidates, so TWP was bound to win regardless.

Comment: Congratulations, guys!  It was a strong field of candidates, and any one of you would have been a worthy addition to the moderation team.  Thank you all for putting your hand up to help us keep The Workplace the great community it is.

Comment: Thank you sir! I am still shocked as to how things turned out this way. :) It will take me a couple of days to get over the shock and rise up to the challenge.

Answer (score 5):

Having recovered a bit from the shocking result, I am here to express my gratitude. I am grateful to the community for <s>tolerating</s> supporting me until now, and now electing me as a moderator.

This is flattering beyond my expectations. I thought I could walk away from this election with my head held high if I could get 10 third choice votes. The community clearly [sees me a little better](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouAreBetterThanYouThinkYouAre) than that, which brings back memories of the [first question I asked here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/20515/3192).

I have <s>always</s> usually tried being helpful as a "regular" user, and I will use my new position to serve the community even better.

Congratulations to [Snow](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/44108/snow), you truly deserve the promotion!

Comment: Congratulation Masked Man :)

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to both.  TWP is in excellent hands.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations gentlemen, you both deserve it.